# How to print dataframe statistics?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Is there any built in function on DataFrame type that would enable me to print out a dataframe containing number of Females for each level of education? I want to perform some stats on the dataset.
I want to have 1 column with Education and another another one with Number of Females as in:

```
Education    Number
High School  5
Bachelor     7
College      19
```

Original Df
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y8VdU1Y7jGR17vWDspm31PdL-d1BQlDg/view?usp=sharing

At the moment I am extracting this way:

```
#subset myDataFrame based on Gender's value, returns boolean series
isFemale = myDataFrame['Gender']=='Female'

# =============================================================================
#fileter dataframe based on boolean condition, extract female column as df
femaleDataframe = myDataFrame[isFemale]

print("women  in High Scool " + str(femaleDataframe["Education"].str.contains("High School or Below").sum()))
print("women  in   College " + str(femaleDataframe["Education"].str.contains("College").sum()))
print("women  in   Bachelor  " + str(femaleDataframe["Education"].str.contains("Bachelor").sum()))

print("total females" + str(countFemales))
```

Comment: Hey, a couple of points. 1) You should try to be more careful with question titles in the future. Yours is rather generic, which will tend to make it harder for people to know whether they can contribute a meaningful answer. 2) I didn't feel like writing out a full answer, but have you looked at pandas groupby's? They will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with your provided CSV, this script will print all Females grouped by `Education`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

print( df[df['Gender']=='Female'].groupby('Education').size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Number'}) )
```

Prints:

```
              Education  Number
0              Bachelor      39
1               College     128
2  High School or Below     117
3       Master or Above       3
```

Comment: I had thought that  ```rename(columns={0:'Number'})``` would make column Number the first one in the data set, but it looks like it's the second one. First column is Education according to your code.

Comment: Now I understand, by default Number column would be named ```0``` initially, hence the reason why you renamed it.

Comment: @bibscy Yes, after `.reset_index()` the column is named `0` -> so I rename it to `Number`